# Move files older than day

Tags: directory, find, date, mv

I am looking for some solution, where I have to move all the directories and files under the source directory to the destination a day before. I want to move the directories till yesterday but not today’s.

```
find  /temp/source/* -mtime +1 -exec mv -t /temp/destination/ {} \;
```

Comment: Take a look at this question on stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902104/moving-files-older-than-one-day

Comment: This looks something different to my requirement... I wanted to move directories and folders from source to destination.

Comment: Create a file with a timestamp of midnight, then use `find -newer`.

Comment: Have you looked into using `rsync` with the `--include-from=FILE` option, so that you can first rsync the files listed in a text file you created with `find`, then delete those files after you confirm the destination looks right?

Comment: Hi the thing is I want to move the directoriesj and each day the directory gets created with respect to the date. So I wanted to move the directories one day before which are older..

Answer (score 0):

You need `daystart` if you want to catch all files up to yesterday 23:59 o'clock:

> Measure times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin,
> and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from
> 24 hours ago.  This option only affects tests which appear
> later on the command line.

Example:

```
find /temp/source/* -daystart -mtime +0
```

Or of you want all files only of today

```
find /temp/source/* -daystart -mtime 0
```

Or all files only of yesterday

```
find /temp/source/* -daystart -mtime 1
```

You can even define a specific range of days like all files of yesterday and the day before yesterday:

```
find /temp/source/* -daystart -mtime +0 -mtime -3
```

PS You should consider `-mindepth 1` instead of globbing (`*`) the subdirectories to `find`.